# Spring Boot 2 | Defining @RequestMapping in interfaces

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have created a simple spring-boot-starter-web(v2.1.5) project that needs to implement "controller" classes for the @RequestMapping interfaces generated by OpenApi/Swagger

This is how the generated interface looks:-

```
@Validated
@Api(value = "passbook", description = "the passbook API")
public interface PassbookApi {

    default Optional<NativeWebRequest> getRequest() {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get passbook information for a given account number", nickname = "fetchPassbook", notes = "", response = PagedTransactionDetails.class, tags={ "passbook", })
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Passbook information", response = PagedTransactionDetails.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/passbook",
        produces = { "application/json" }, 
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
    default ResponseEntity<PagedTransactionDetails> fetchPassbook(@NotNull @ApiParam(value = "Account Number", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "accountNumber", required = true) String accountNumber,@ApiParam(value = "Offset for transactions to be displayed") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "offset", required = false) Integer offset,@ApiParam(value = "Last transaction serial number") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "transactionSerialNumber", required = false) String transactionSerialNumber,@ApiParam(value = "Last transactionId") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "transactionId", required = false) String transactionId,@ApiParam(value = "Last amount value") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "amountValue", required = false) Integer amountValue) {
        getRequest().ifPresent(request -> {
            for (MediaType mediaType: MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"))) {
                if (mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.valueOf("application/json"))) {
                    ApiUtil.setExampleResponse(request, "application/json", "{  \"txns\" : [ {    \"asdf\" : \"asdf\"  }, {    \"asdf\" : \"asdf\"  } ]}");
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);

    }

}
```

It's implementation:-

```
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
class PassbookController implements PassbookApi {
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<PagedTransactionDetails> fetchPassbook(@NotNull @Valid String accountNumber,
                                                                 @Valid Integer offset, @Valid String transactionSerialNumber, @Valid String transactionId, @Valid Integer amountValue) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new PagedTransactionDetails()); // !! THIS NEVER GETS INVOKED
    }
}
```

The request handler method DO get invoked when I remove the `implements PassbookApi` part and annotate the method with @RequestMapping

How can I get it to work while using `implements PassbookApi` & not annotating the method with @RequestMapping again in the implementing class.

I am testing using MockMVC

Maven plugin:-

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>spring-server</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/account-summary-api.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                            <library>spring-boot</library>
                            <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-openapi/spring</output>
                            <generateApis>true</generateApis>
                            <addCompileSourceRoot>true</addCompileSourceRoot>
                            <artifactVersion>${project.version}</artifactVersion>
                            <groupId>com.x.summary.generated</groupId>
                            <artifactId>account-summary-api</artifactId>
                            <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                            <modelPackage>com.x.summary.generated.model</modelPackage>
                            <apiPackage>com.x.summary.generated.api</apiPackage>
                            <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                            <configOptions>
                                <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
                                <java8>true</java8>
                                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                                <reactive>false</reactive>
                                <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
                                <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
                                <useOptional>false</useOptional>
                                <serviceInterface>true</serviceInterface>
                                <serviceImplementation>false</serviceImplementation>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I don't understand what's not working?

Comment: A different question: do you need the interface ? I have seen similar implementations many times (some even with additional abstract classes) and none of them added additional value but only confusion

Comment: @SimonMartinelli when I do a GET /passbook, I get 404 in response

Comment: @Marged I get your point. In my use case, I am generating the MVC interfaces, request & response DTO as part of my maven build ( see updated question) instead of one time generating the whole spring boot/mvc module using its openapi generator.

Comment: Only with mockmvc or else too? I have a same configuration and it works for me

Comment: @SimonMartinelli else too.

Comment: I took your code and it works. I call GET http://localhost:8080/passbook?accountNumber=1 How does your call looks like?